# Clearing mocks for each integration tests by JMockit

Tags: java, testng, integration-testing, jmockit

I have got a problem in connection with JMockit 
@Mocked annotation.

I prepared fields with this annotation which are executed by TestNG (mocked objects for executing tests).

Is there any possibility to reset/clear these mocks in declared function with @After... annotation?